# Trying to put 2 links beside each other so they are the same height in css grid

Tags: css, css-grid, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to use css grid to place 2 links beside each other to be the same height with text centered both vertically and horizontally, regardless of how much text is in each link.

The grid itself is centered vertically, but the text does not fill the entire grid cell.  Is it not possible to  make the 2 links the same height?

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/stevea777/pen/VwXPZQE

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}

a.button {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  align-self: center;
}

a:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a class="button">Batman</a>
  <a class="button">Spiderman eats Cornbread with Maple Syrup</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `height: 100%` to `a.button` class:

```css
.box{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
   grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
 
}
a.button{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  }
a:nth-child(2){
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a class="button">Batman</a>
  <a class="button">Spiderman eats Cornbread with Maple Syrup</a>
</div>
```

Comment: But then I lose my vertical centering, and the text is at the top, not in the middle. :/

Comment: @StephenAsh  Ok, I have updated the css, can u have a look at it if this is what u want to achieve?